# IBM PushNotification: Not Found - The target resource 'PushDevice' does not exist

Tags: angularjs, node.js, ibm-cloud, ibm-mobile-services

i try to using the API swagger **PUT /apps/{applicationId}/devices/{deviceId}** at https://mobile.ng.bluemix.net/imfpush/#!/devices/put_apps_applicationId_devices_deviceId . But I have a error message

```
{
  "code": "FPWSE0001E",
  "message": "Not Found - The target resource 'PushDevice' does not exist. Check the '23e107c7292d17a772914af05c23d10750613aaa' parameter."
}
```

Please help give me your thoughts

Comment: Can you say what you were trying to do? If possible, include the code you were running when you got the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The application or the device doesn't exist

```
{
  "code": "FPWSE0001E",
  "message": "Not Found - Targeted resource 'PushApplication' does not exist. Check the 'UnknownApplication' parameter"
}
```

means that the application or the device that you've provided doesn't exist.

It looks like you're trying to update the device registration from the REST API, so you'll want to make sure that you check all of the registered devices you currently have by getting a list of the current devices:

`GET /apps/{applicationId}/devices`

I'm not sure what you're particular use-case is, but in most cases, you shouldn't have to update the device registration, and any kind of behavior that you need will be included in the client SDK. [See the docs](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/mobilepush/index.html) for more information.